# Can Find My iPhone be linked to multiple devices?

Tags: find-my-iphone, iphone

I lost my iPhone 7. While tracking it with Find My iPhone, it died and is now offline. I can't see its last location. I have tried for a week now waiting to see if someone turns the phone on so I can track its location.

If I sign into my Apple ID on my old iPhone 5, will I still be able to see my iPhone 7 on Find My iPhone if someone turns it on later?

Comment: Yes you will be able to

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can have multiple devices linked to a single Apple ID each with Find My iPhone turned on, and they will be tracked individually. You can switch between showing different devices (or all devices) using the link at the top of Find My iPhone.